# Setting multiple font of different label in tableview cell based on web response

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to do a simple thing but getting strange issue. What I am trying to do is setting a label's font bold based on the web-response. the no of cell would be in hundreds. At first it loads properly, but when i scroll up or down, the font of first some labels also getting bold while the `noteStautus` is still . Here is the code, which I have implemented. Here is the code for the table view data-source. On the basis of value of `noteStatus` I am changing the label's font size. Simply what I want is if the `noteStatus =0` text font should be bold, otherwise simple font.

```
NSDictionary* response=(NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&tempError];
    notificationList = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSArray *notificationArray = response[@"Notifications"];
    for(NSDictionary *notificationDict in notificationArray)
    {
        NSDictionary *cellData =@{@"noteStatus":[notificationDict valueForKey:@"status_read"],@"notificationId":[notificationDict valueForKey:@"notification_id"]};

        [notificationList addObject:cellData];
    }
}
[self.notificationTableview reloadData];`
```

**Checking-condition**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NotificationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"notificationCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell==nil)
{
    cell = [[NotificationCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"notificationCell"];
}
if([[[notificationList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"noteStatus"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
{
[cell.notificationReviewLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
cell.notificationReviewLabel.text = [[notificationList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"messageNo"];
cell.dateLabel.text = [[notificationList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"dateNo"];
}
else
{

    cell.notificationReviewLabel.text = [[notificationList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"messageNo"];
    cell.dateLabel.text = [[notificationList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"dateNo"];
 }

return cell;
}
```

Comment: in else part write [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

because when uitableview scroll it's reuse display cell . and use previously set property

Comment: Thanks bhargav :) missed that little thing and was annoyed since 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset font in **else** statement to

```
[cell.notificationReviewLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
```

You see, as you reuse the cell, it saves most recent formatting.
Better practice is overriding *prepareForReuse* for NotificationCell where you reset all formatting to default